# calculating x to power y using for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, long-integer

I've tried to use the `for` loop for calculating x to power y. The program is running but giving errors.

To my knowledge, the error must be in "z" statements but I cannot figure it out.
Help me if you encounter my mistakes.

````c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{

    int x,y,i;
    long int z=x;

    printf("Enter the values of x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

    for(i=2;i<=y;i++)   
        z*=x;     ```
                  /*e.g-  Let x=2, y=3, then as per intialization z=x=2
                          since,from the for condition, (i=2)<=3, which is true
                          z= z*x =>2*2 => 4 now z=4
                          now i++ => i=3
                          (i=3)<=3,which is true
                          z= z*x =>4*2 => 8
                          therefore, 2 to power 3 is 8 */ 

    printf("%d to power %d is %ld",x,y,z);
    getch();

}
````

Comment: `long int z=x;` this is undefined behavior. You never set `z` to anything valid.

Comment: Hint: The initial value of `z` needs to be multiplicative identity.

Comment: Think about the order in which you do things. In C nothing is done retroactively.

Comment: Assuming you fixed that assignment to z, then what do you think your result will be for y == 0? Or even y < 0? Suppose you don't want to get `x` reprinted then...

Comment: Off-topic: It's not the task of a console application to keep the console window open. All you actually achieve that way is preventing your programme from being runnable within scripts, so better stay away from stuff like `getch()` or `system("pause")` for such purpose. Rather run your programme from within an IDE, which usually offers it's own console, or just open your console window separately.

Comment: Just as comment: You also can use `pow()` in `math.h`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio `pow(double)` can readily have less integer precision than `long`.  Perhaps 53 vs. 64.  `pow(double)` good for an approximate answer.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio *And* you can get bad result, assuming you want to cast back to integer, like `long x = std::pow(12, 1)` resulting in `x` being 11...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I did not read the source code accurately that she explicitly wants `long` calculation. Thanks for the hint. What about `powl()`?

Comment: @Blaze Didn´t you mean: *"You never set `x` to anything valid."* instead of *"You never set `z` to anything valid."* ? Well, there is a coherence but though.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio no, `x` is set to something valid in the `scanf` (assuming that the user gives proper input). `z`, on the other hand, is never anything valid. There's the `long int z=x;` assignment while `x` is uninitialized, and then there's `z*=x` after that while `z` is still invalid.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I think I get what you're saying now. If "set" is past tense, then `x` was indeed never set to anything valid prior to the `z=x`. I didn't mean it that way, looks like my comment was ambiguous. :)

Comment: @Blaze Yes, that was my thought, only in the context of the first assignment of `long int z=x;`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio `powl()` might have more precision (80, 113) than `long`, (64, 32) maybe not (54).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Would this be a disadvantage if it has more precision?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Even with `powl()` having more precision than `long`, we still run into inexact-ness issues of `powl()` only providing a _good_ result with integer input rather than an _exact_ result.  Such is the quality of implementation for FP functions.  `powl()` may result in x.99999... when `x+1` is expected.  With rounding and additional code, much of this can be mitigated, yet for integer problems like OP's, an integer based solution typical provides the best portable results vs. mixing a FP function in.

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning `z` to `x` before `x` is assigned a value. `z` then has an indeterminate value, which messes up calculation of the power.

You have to wait until `x` is assigned from user input before using its value to initialize `z`.

Also, when reading input from `scanf`, it's a best practice to check its return value to ensure that all intended values were read successfully:

```
if(scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2)
{
    // x and y were not properly read - handle error
}

z = x;
```

EDIT: @chux - Reinstate Monica pointed out in the comments that if `y == 0` the code still has a problem. Anything to the power of zero (except zero itself, since x<sup>y</sup> is not continuous at the origin) is 1. You have to handle that special case as well.

Comment: Actually, as user allows `int`, you'll have to care for negative powers as well...

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing your `z` variable (to be equal to `x`) **before** you have assigned a value to `x`! To fix this, move the declaration/initialization of `z` to *after* your `scanf` call:

```c
    //..
    int x,y,i;
//  long int z=x; // Means nothing: as "x" is here undefined, so "z" will also be!

    printf("Enter the values of x and y: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    long int z = x; // Here, we have (probably) a value for "x" so we can copy it to "z"
    //..
```

EDIT: Maybe I'm drifting a bit 'off-topic' here, but you *may* have a background in programming languages that use **reference** variables (C++ or C#)? In such languages, what you are *trying* to do may work! For example, in C++, you could have `int& z = x;` (where you have your current declaration), and that could work in *some* circumstances (although, in your code, it actually won't, as pointed out in the comments). However, in "plain old C," code is executed where you put it, and there's no such thing as a "reference variable."

Comment: Making it a reference to x would clobber x when z is changed.

Comment: I got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you might want to initialize those variables

```
long int x = 0, y = 0;
long int z = 0;
```

Here you should check if `scanf` was successful

```
printf("Enter the values of x and y: ");
scanf("%ld %ld",&x,&y);
```

About `scanf` return value. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

> Return value 1-3) Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned
>   (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the
>   first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs
>   before the first receiving argument was assigned. 4-6) Same as (1-3),
>   except that EOF is also returned if there is a runtime constraint
>   violation.

Now the problem is you're assigning `z` the value of `x` before either is initialized properly. So that is an undefined behavior.

This is what you want

```
long int x = 0, y = 0;
long int z = 0;

printf("Enter the values of x and y: ");
scanf("%ld %ld",&x,&y);

z = x;
```

Also you can define a new `int` variable inside the loop. I personally find this method better.

```
for(int i = 2; i <= y; i++) 
    z *= x;
```

For the `print` statement, you might want to use `%ld` format for `long int`

```
printf("%ld to power %ld is %ld",x,y,z);
```

Comment: To assign `z` on declaration is a good idea, yet code could instead of `long int z = 0; ... z = x;` simply do `long int z = x;` after the `scanf()`.

Comment: I got it, Thanks!